# What is a 3-phase H-bridge called?

Tags: h-bridge

Simple question. An H-bridge has two phases by default - two half-bridges. But it can also be constructed with 3 or more halves.

I assume it isn't called an ├├│-bridge :)

For the benefit of Andy Aka:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foXe7u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A suggestion - "Y-bridge"

Comment: Where does the load connect? Show a schematic please.

Comment: @Andyaka same as an H-bridge - but three wires

Comment: @user253751 my question is aimed at the op exclusively.

Comment: @Andyaka that would be me. You are now seeing a schematic.

Comment: I'd call it a 3-phase full bridge.

Comment: "*3-phase bridge*" or simply "*3-phase ..."* depending on the topology. The latter is rather common for buck regulators for example.